# Server Fault retag: gpo to group-policy

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

These guys: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/gpo

go here: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/group-policy

Answer (score 2):

This is complete, and a synonym is in place.